# Square root of PSD matrix and unitary freedom

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Consider a **given** PSD matrix $S$, which can be written as:

$$S= A A^\top$$

where $A$ is its unique PSD square root. I am computing $A$ through the EVD of $S= U DU^\top$, i.e., $A= U D^{1/2}U^\top$.

I want to fit a model to $S$ as:

\begin{equation}
S= B(\theta) B(\theta)^\top
\end{equation}
and specifically I look after the parameter $\theta$ from which the square matrix $B$ depends.

My final goal is to use $B(\theta)$ in place of $A$. Now, I would be tempted to  consider the following simpler problem:

$$A= B(\theta)$$

I know that in principle $A=B(\theta) Q $ for any orthogonal matrix $Q$. However, what I care about is not to find a $\theta$ which is equal to a true unknown parameter $\theta^\star$, rather I  just want that a $\theta$ for which $B(\theta)B(\theta)^\top=S$. So my initial line of thought was to just discard the $Q$ since at the end when I multiply $B(\theta) Q Q^\top B(\theta)^\top$ the $Q$ would simply vanish.

What is wrong with this line of thought?
Thank you.

Comment: The problem with discarding the $Q$ is that you might run into a situation where $A = B(\theta)$ has no solution, but $S = B(\theta)B(\theta)^\top$ does have a solution

Comment: And if I consider the $Q$ do I necessarily find a solution?

Comment: If $S=B(\theta)B(\theta)^\top$ has a solution, then so does $A=B(\theta)Q$

Comment: Even if a solution does exists,  optimization-wise I cannot guarantee that if I use an alternating minimization approach on $\theta$ and $Q$, I end up in one of the solutions, I guess (?).

Comment: I think alternating minimization is still worth a try, though. Note that the optimal $Q$ for a given $\theta$ is pretty quick to find using a variant of the solution to the “orthogonal procrustes problem”

Comment: Alternatively, if we can guarantee that the rank of $B(\theta)$ is always equal to that of $S$, I think that the $Q$-optimization can be replaced with a simple QR decomposition

Comment: Yes the rank of $B(\theta)$ and $S$ are usually equal. Are you aware if it matters which step, among $\theta$-minimization and $Q$-minimization, is the first? (This is important for the initialization of one of the variables).

To which matrix would you apply QR?

Comment: I don’t think it matters. I’ll try to explain my QR idea in an answer when I have time

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for the comments. I came back after all this time since I had to absent myself from the work I was carrying on. Could you elaborate on how to see and understand your first comment where you mention the case that $S=..$ has a solution but $A=..$ does not have? And it's connection to your second comment, where adding the $Q$ changes things. You can also edit your answer as introduction. I am going to read your answer

Comment: See my edit. Hopefully the example clarifies things for you

Comment: Does the matrix necessarily need to be orthogonal?

Comment: If $B$ has full rank, yes. Otherwise no, but the kind of matrix $Q$ can be is still restricted

Comment: What is the line of thought you follow when giving these answers? Are you thinking "by example" or "by theorems/properties of matrices" when giving the above two answers? To understand how I can fill these gaps and which notions should I reinforce. Thanks

Comment: All this can be framed in terms of polar decomposition, that’s how I’ve been thinking about it. I’ll spell out the connection in another edit. Correction to my previous comment: it’s specifically if $B$ has full row rank where $Q$ must be orthogonal

Comment: Thanks for your effort and clarity, I will accept the answer and go over it as soon as I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that illustrates that $S = B(\theta)B(\theta)^\top$ might have a solution when $A = B(\theta)$ doesn't.  For instance, consider
$$
S = \pmatrix{2 & 3\\3 & 5}, \quad A = \pmatrix{1 & 1\\1 & 2}, \quad B(\theta) = \pmatrix{1 & -1\\1 & \theta}.
$$
It is clear that $B(\theta) = A$ has no solution. However, we have $B(\theta)B(\theta)^\top = S$ with $\theta = -2$.

On the other hand, there exists an orthogonal $Q$ such that $B(\theta)Q = A$. Indeed, this holds with
$$
Q = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}.
$$

---

Let $S$ be $n \times n$ and let $r$ denote the (known) rank of $S$. Because of what is [stated here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Positive_semidefinite_matrices), there exists a unique "lower-triangular" $n \times r$ matrix $L_*$ with positive diagonal entries such that $S = L_*L_*^\top$. That is,
$$
L_* = \pmatrix{L_1\\L_2}
$$
where $L_1$ is square and lower-triangular (with positive diagonal entries).  Suppose that for all $\theta$, $B(\theta)$ has rank $r$. For any $\theta$, let $L(\theta)$ denote the $n \times r$ "lower-triangular" matrix (with positive diagonal entries) obtained from the [LQ decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#QL,_RQ_and_LQ_decompositions)
$$
B(\theta) = L(\theta) Q(\theta),
$$
where $Q(\theta)$ has orthonormal rows. As with the Cholesky decomposition, the $L(\theta)$ obtained in this fashion is unique. We find that $S = B(\theta)B(\theta)^\top$ has a solution if and only if $L_* = L(\theta)$ has a solution. If $\theta_*$ is such that $L(\theta_*) = L_*$, then it immediately follows that
$$
B(\theta_*) B(\theta_*)^\top = L_*L_*^\top = S.
$$
Note that the LQ-decomposition is related to the QR-decomposition as follows:
$$
A = LQ \iff A^\top = Q^\top L^\top,
$$
where we note that $Q^\top$ has orthonormal columns and $L^\top$ is upper-triangular.

---

If it is desired, we can get a solution to $A = B(\theta)Q$ (with $Q$ orthogonal) as follows: Let $\tilde L_*$ denote the square matrix $[L_*\ \ 0]$. If $\tilde L_* = U \Sigma V^\top$ is a singular value decomposition, then $S = U\Sigma^2 U^\top$ and $A = U \Sigma U^\top$, which means that $A = \tilde L_* UV^\top$, or equivalently $L_* = AVU^\top$. We can add rows to $Q(\theta_*)$ to make an orthogonal matrix $Q_*$. We have
$$
B(\theta_*) = \tilde L_* Q_* = (AVU^\top)Q_* = A[VU^TQ_*] \implies\\
A = B(\theta_*)Q_*^\top UV^\top.
$$

---

Some notes on the connection between polar decomposition and this problem:

- Every matrix $A$ can be written in the form $A = PU$ for a positive semidefinite matrix $P$ and a matrix $U$ satisfying $UU^T = I$. This decomposition is unique if and only if $A$ has full row-rank; in this case, $P = \sqrt{AA^T}$ and $U$ can be expressed as
  $$
  U = P^{-1}A = \left[\sqrt{AA^T}\right]^{-1} A.
  $$
- If matrices $A,B$ of the same shape satisfy $AA^T = BB^T$, then there is a single positive semidefinite matrix $P$ such that $A = PU_1$ and $B = PU_2$ for orthogonal matrices $U_1,U_2$.

---

Proof of the fact that $S = B(\theta)B(\theta)^\top$ has a solution if and only if $L_\star = L(\theta)$ has a solution.

If $L_\star = L(\theta)$ has a solution $\theta_\star$, then it follows that
$$
B(\theta_\star)B(\theta_\star)^\top = L(\theta_\star)L(\theta_\star)^\top = L_\star L_\star^\top = S.
$$

Conversely, suppose that $S = B(\theta)B(\theta)^\top$ has a solution $\theta_\star$. It follows that $L(\theta_\star)L(\theta_\star)^\top = S$. Now, we have $L(\theta_\star)L(\theta_\star)^\top = L_\star L_\star^\top$. From the above statements about the polar decomposition, it follows that $L_\star = L(\theta_\star)U$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$. That is,
$$
L_\star I = L(\theta_\star)U
$$
are $LQ$ decompositions of the same matrix. It follows that $L_\star = L(\theta_\star)$ and that $I = U$.

---

Note: I was wrong– it is not necessarily the case that a solution to $S = L_\star L_\star^T$ exists, but if such an $L_\star$ exists, then it is unique.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I will have a look soon and get back to you :)

Comment: Essentially the if and only if statement you mention holds because the two triangular factors $L_\star$ and $L(\theta)$ are the unique triangular factors for $S$ and $B(\theta)$, respectively? 
How do you exclude the existence of another orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $L_\star = L(\theta) Q$?

Comment: On another note: suppose that instead of solving $S = B(\theta) B(\theta)^\top$ for $\theta$, I can now solve $L_\star = L(\theta)$, i.e., fitting the two factors. Although I can easily compute $L_\star$ from my $S$, now the problem is that the influence of $\theta$ in the factor $L(\theta)$ is not 'visible' anymore, I do not have an explicit formula for it. Which optimization procedure would you recommend then? A manual LQ decomposition of my $B(\theta)$? :D

Comment: @VanBaffo To your first question, yes: uniqueness guarantees that if $L(\theta)L(\theta)^T = L_\star L_\star^T$, then $L(\theta) = L_\star$

Comment: @VanBaffo To your second question, explicit formulas and optimization procedures don't really overlap very often. If you want an explicit formula for $\theta$ in terms of $S$, you could always try plugging that equation into some symbolic math solver (e.g. Mathematica or Maple) and see if anything nice pops out. If you're looking for some kind of gradient for the purposes of optimization, you can get that without an explicit formula using some kind of autograd functionality

Comment: To your first answer: why can you exclude the existence of an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @VanBaffo Again, because of uniqueness. By "uniqueness", I mean that if $L_1Q_1 = L_2 Q_2 = B$ are two decompositions satisfying the conditions I outlined, then $L_1 = L_2$ and $Q_1 = Q_2$. It cannot be the case that either $L_2 \neq L_1$ or that $Q_2 \neq Q_1$.

Comment: I am confused. I am referring to IFF statement you mention, and I am confused on the fact that if there is an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that  $L_\star= L(\theta) Q$ then $ L_\star L_\star^\top= L(\theta) Q Q^\top L(\theta)^\top = L(\theta) L(\theta)^\top$. I don't know what is bugging me

Comment: @VanBaffo See my edit to the question. Also, I made a bit of an error regarding $L_\star$; there exist matrices $S$ for which no suitable $L_\star$ exists.

Comment: Trying to absorb the concepts. First: why if there exists a $\theta$ such that $B(\theta) B(\theta)^\top=S$ has a solution, then there exists an orthogonal $Q$ such that $A = B(\theta)Q$ has a solution? I mean in the case in which $A=B(\theta)$ does not have a solution. Why the existence of an orthogonal matrix satisfying the equation is a fact? I see it from the example, but not as a given fact.

Comment: @VanBaffo See the second fact within my discussion of polar decomposition

Comment: I am slowly wrapping up when I have time.. however I think that your error is not an error, since you can always find a Cholesky decomposition for any PSD matrix.

Comment: @VanBaffo I'll have to double check that when I can. The usual fact is true for the ordinary Cholesky decomposition, but these low-rank "tall" Cholesky factorizations might be a different story

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149321/discussion-between-vanbaffo-and-ben-grossmann).